# Make error in installing Math support for MediaWiki

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mediawiki

How can you solve the following Make error in installing MediaWiki?

```
...

/local/lib/site_perl . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/maint/php-tag.t line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/maint/php-tag.t line 8.
# Looks like your test died before it could output anything.
t/maint/php-tag..........dubious                                             
        Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
t/maint/unix-newlines....ok                                                  
Failed Test            Stat Wstat Total Fail  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/00-test.t             127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Database.t        127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Global.t          127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/IP.t              127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/ImageFunctions.t  127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Language.t        127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Licenses.t        127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/LocalFile.t       127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Parser.t          127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Revision.t        127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Sanitizer.t       127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Search.t          127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Title.t           127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/inc/Xml.t             127 32512    ??   ??  ??
t/maint/php-lint.t      254 65024   966  966  1-966
t/maint/php-tag.t       255 65280    ??   ??  ??
Failed 16/19 test scripts. 966/4248 subtests failed.
Files=19, Tests=4248, 46 wallclock secs (33.15 cusr + 10.38 csys = 43.53 CPU)
Failed 16/19 test programs. 966/4248 subtests failed.
make: *** [test] Error 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just googled ... 
http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/ubuntu-users@lists.ubuntu.com/6817776.html

maybe it helps.

Comment: I am not sure what these steps mean *remember you have to change the debian/changelog for the new version
after copying the old debian directory into the new version.* since I am not updating my mediawiki.

*3. If this still fails, try building it normally just to see if it will.
  If so, it may give you a clue where you need to adjust the
debian/rules file for differences in the versions.* - I did build the app normally first by downloading the app from their internet site and following all instructions in the README.

Comment: I guess you missed to install a needed package. cause you tag in ubuntu you have apt. On my debian machine searching for apt-cache search php tag, it shows me php-simpletest - Unit testing and web testing framework for PHP. And in your example from above the unit testing fails.  Maybe it has something todo with that.

Do you downloaded the source directly to build it or did you fetched it with apt and want to build a source package?